# how suppress auto build in ide for my winform usercontrols

Tags: c#

i have several initialization items in my Load event that I would like to suppress when the project is opened in the vs2008 IDE. is there a directive that I can place in front of my c# code that would prevent execution.

.net 2.0

Comment: IMO question title has very little in common with question body

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could check for [`DesignMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.component.designmode.aspx) in the `Load` event handler.